# How to augment the mocha module?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, cypress, module-augmentation

Given Cypress 10.3.1 which has Mocha 3.5.3 in [devDependencies](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/package.json).

I want to add new functions to mocha `Context`.

In `cypress/support/e2e.ts` I do `import './context';`. And in `cypress/support/context.ts` I have:

```
import { Context } from 'mocha';

declare module 'mocha' {
    export interface Context {
        sayHelloWorld();
    }
}

Context.prototype.sayHelloWorld = function () {
    cy.log('hello world');
};
```

Visual Studio lets me call the new function on `Context` (code completion). But when trying to run any test I get:

```
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'mocha' from 'C:\…\cypress\support\context.ts'
```

Is this possibly a bundler issue? If I remove the browserify setup (which I need for something else), I get a different error instead:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/context.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mocha' in 'C:\…\cypress\support'
…
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

Do I have to install Mocha manually to my own project? If I do so (`yarn add -D mocha@3.5.3`), again I get a different error instead:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
```

Any idea how to do this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. no `import { Context } from "mocha";`
2. add new functions like that:

```
declare module 'mocha' {
    export interface Context {
        sayHelloWorld();
    }
}

Mocha.Context.prototype.sayHelloWorld = function () {
    cy.log('hello world');
};
```

3. now you can use them in your tests like that:

```
it('works', function () {
    this.sayHelloWorld();
})
```

**Important:** For some reason, there is no `Context` available in `() => {` so you must use `function () {` like shown above.